# Why does the sort() method does't work as expected with an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm experimenting with the sort() method in JavaScript. The documentation says the return value should be `> 0` to sort `b` before `a`. I have the following code to reverse an array of strings, and have the return value as a positive integer, which I think should sort the array in the reverse order:

```
let nums = ["x", "y", "z"];
nums.sort((a, b) => 1); // returning a positive number to sort b before a
console.log(nums)
```

However, when I execute the code, the output is:

```
[ 'x', 'y', 'z' ] // not reversed at all
```

But the code does give me the expected value - `[ 'z', 'y', 'x' ]` - when I set the return value to a negative number. Is there an explanation for this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How do you know what `a` and `b` are? You’re not even looking at them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because the `callback` of `sort` method, takes two params but they do not correspond as one would think to *first second third...etc... elements* but on the contrary, `a` is the second element, `b` is the first one, so when it says that a number greater than 1 places `b` ahead of `a` that's what it does:

```js
const nums = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

nums.sort((a, b) => {
  console.log(a,b)  // yx -zy
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are not conditionally check out `a` and `b` which is greater or lesser. Returning 1 will evaluate first parameter from `sort((a, b)` is greater. Which returns you exact same array.

You better compare those to value inside sort callback function and depending on value return 1 or -1.

This will result ascending order.

```js
let nums = ["x", "y", "z"];
nums.sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1);
console.log(nums)
```

Toggle return value to get descending order.

```js
let nums = ["x", "y", "z"];
nums.sort((a, b) => a > b ? -1 : 1);
console.log(nums)
```